# call exe from wcf service

Tags: c#, wcf, exe

We have a `WCF` service that we recently switched from self-hosting to `IIS-hosted`. It needs to launch an executable using `Process.Start()`. This works fine when it's self-hosted, but when hosted in `IIS`, we get the error:

> TimeOutException was unhandled

```
void notepad()
{
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("notepad").waitForExit();
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you host your WCF service in IIS, being a server, IIS requires and allows no user interaction and works also if no user is logged in; in that context there is no UI to host your notepad or other UI enabled applications, you could execute a process or other batch jobs but not render a windows UI application, because Windows Explorer is not loaded for you and there is no place to render your process's UI. So you can start processes that have no UI.

Comment: Add a try-catch block and see where the exception is coming from, it may not be coming from here.

Comment: it comes from System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("notepad").waitForExit();

Comment: can i run cmd without window?And call notepad from cmd?

Comment: Remove waitforexit() just have System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("notepad"); the Exception should go away